# css :first-child with class selector picking up wrong elements to style?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is the HTML code, I don't understand why the `<a>` tag in the second `<p>` has brown color:

```css
.entry-content :first-child {
  color: brown
}
```

```html
<article id="post-5946">
  <section class="entry-content">
    <p>
      <a href="#">HTML5 From Scratch</a>Very proud to announce my latest Pluralsight Course:
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">HTML5 From Scratch</a>Very proud to announce my latest Pluralsight Course:
    </p>
  </section>
</article>
```

when you look at this page I get two paragraphs, the first is all brown along with  tag and in second paragraph only  is brown which shouldn't be the case i.e. in second paragraph there shouldn't be any change in color.

output: 
[image]

Comment: Use the devtools style explorer to see the styles applied to the second `a` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.entry-content :first-child` selects all descendants of `.entry-content` to see if they're the first child of their parent.

Since the second `<a>` tag is the first child of its parent *and* it's a descendant of `.entry-content`, it gets the style.

You want to check only `.entry-content`'s immediate children, which you can do with:

```
.entry-content > :first-child
```

Assuming you want the first paragraph *and* its contents to be brown, do this:

**Snippet:**

```css
.entry-content > :first-child,
.entry-content > :first-child * {
  color: brown
}
```

```html
<section class="entry-content">
  <p>
    <a href="#">HTML5 From Scratch</a>Very proud to announce my latest Pluralsight Course:
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">HTML5 From Scratch</a>Very proud to announce my latest Pluralsight Course:
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! @Rich Hitchcock

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer. is there a way to find who did? because my question is also downvoted

Comment: No way to tell, but your question certainly didn't deserve a downvote either.

Comment: same to your answer, I got what I needed from your answer, do you know if there is a way to flag this to any admin etc?

Comment: I don't think it would do any good.  Questions and answers get voted down all the time, it's just part of the game.

Comment: that's true, but it affects the reputation, which will bugs people with a low reputation like me lol